# What does the suffix 'w' and 'd' mean with 'TIME+' in top?

Tags: linux, top, uptime

Here's a chunk of the `top` from my server:

```
PID    USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM      TIME+  COMMAND    
18878  www-data  20   0  200m  13m 4704 S    0  0.2    0:00.07  apache2 
12374  root      20   0  197m 9460 4480 S    0  0.1  21212906w  apache2 
9136   root      20   0 79100 3488 2716 S    0  0.0  54518724d  sshd
```

I know the TIME+ means the total CPU time the task has used since it started. But in the above output, **I simply couldn't understand what `21212906w` and `54518724d` mean?** some considerable no of processes are showing the TIME+ with `w` and `d` prefixed.
What does this mean? Is the server in trouble?

Just to let you know - the server `uptime` is 4days.

**EDIT:**
- I can guess these refer week and days. If so why is it so large considering the uptime?
- The server has 8 cores.

Comment: How many cores does this machine have?

Comment: @Ignacio, 8 cores.

Answer (score 2):

weeks and days

And it looks to me like there's a bug in your version of top, or the kernel, or something... that it's showing bogus numbers there.

Comment: Yes, but why are they so *high*?

Comment: It looks to me like a bug somewhere. I've seen things like that occasionally (and rarely).  Rebooting usually clears the bogus values--in this case restarting the offending processes probably would, too.

Comment: Yea, I have guessed it, `week` and `days`, but why are they so high considering my uptime?

Comment: Another option is that you have 37122585 CPU cores that have been running constantly since you rebooted 4 days ago, giving you 21212906 weeks of CPU usage... but I'm guessing that's not the real explanation :)